# Error con openssl QT

Tags: qt

Hola obtengo esto error con openssl en qt:

> libeay32.lib(rand_win.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: símbolo externo
>   __imp__DeleteObject@4 sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _readscreen

Básicamente compile en modo estático pero siempre me da problemas el openssl no se que hacer..

Answer (score 1):

El error es de link. El compilador no encuentra la librería.

No has añadido la librería al proyecto. Para añadir una librería externa al proyecto puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
LIBS += -L[path de la librería] -l[nombre de la librería]
```

Si ya has hecho lo anterior y no funciona puede ser que la ruta este mal definida.

Un saludo